Terraform not updating lambda function on AWS
I am trying to update my lambda function via terraform and gitlab ci/cd, but running into an issue where the ci/cd pipeline succeeds and the lambda code on AWS is not updating. I can see that the lambda function is being updated on AWS console (Last Modified shows the right time), but the code does not change. Here is how my code looks like:
.gitlab-ci.yml:
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - "/usr/bin/env"
    - "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

#-------------------- Stages ------------------
stages:
  - import
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply

install_dependencies:
  image: node:18.19.0
  stage: package
  script:
    - cd lambdas/notifications
    - npm ci --cache --prefer-offline
    - cd ../maintenance
    - npm ci --cache --prefer-offline
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
      - lambdas/notifications/node_modules/
      - lambdas/maintenance/node_modules/
  tags:
    - $CDP_K8S_LARGE

# DOCKER BUILD
build-dev-docker:
  extends: .kaniko-package
  stage: package
  variables:
    KANIKO_BUILD_ARGS: "--build-arg ENVIRONMENT=development --single-snapshot"
    EXTRA_DOCKER_TAG: "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG:$CI_PIPELINE_IID"      artifacts:
    paths:
      - lambdas/notifications/lambda_batch.zip
      - lambdas/maintenance/lambda_maintenance.zip
  only:
    refs:
      - develop
  environment:
    name: dev
  tags:
    - $CDP_K8S_LARGE

# TERRAFORM STAGES
import:
  stage: import
  before_script:
    - !reference [default, before_script]
    - source "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/before_script.sh"
  script:
    - terraform import aws_lambda_function.dev-notifications dev-notifications
    - terraform import aws_lambda_function.dev-maintenance dev-maintenance
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - terraform.tfstate

validate:
  stage: validate
  before_script:
    - !reference [default, before_script]
    - source "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/before_script.sh"
  script:
    - terraform validate
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - terraform.tfstate

plan:
  stage: plan
  before_script:
    - !reference [default, before_script]
    - source "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/before_script.sh"
  script:
    - terraform plan -out "planfile"
  dependencies:
    - build-dev-docker
    - validate
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - planfile
      - terraform.tfstate

apply:
  stage: apply
  before_script:
    - !reference [default, before_script]
    - source "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/before_script.sh"
  script:
    - terraform show -json
    - terraform apply -input=false "planfile"
  dependencies:
    - build-dev-docker
    - plan
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - terraform.tfstate

main.tf:
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "dev-notifications" {
    function_name = "dev-notifications"
    role = var.iam_role_arn
    handler = "index.handler"
    runtime = "nodejs20.x"

    filename = "${var.PROJECT_DIR}/lambdas/notifications/lambda_batch.zip"
    source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("${var.PROJECT_DIR}/lambdas/notifications/lambda_batch.zip")

    tags = {
        Application = "dev"
        Ou = "dev"
    }
}

output "notif_output" {
    value = aws_lambda_function.dev-notifications.function_name
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "dev-maintenance" {
    function_name = "dev-maintenance"
    role = var.iam_role_arn
    handler = "index.handler"
    runtime = "nodejs20.x"

    filename = "${var.PROJECT_DIR}/lambdas/maintenance/lambda_maintenance.zip"
    source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("${var.PROJECT_DIR}/lambdas/maintenance/lambda_maintenance.zip")

    tags = {
        Application = "dev"
        Ou = "dev"
    }
}

output "maintenance_output" {
    value = aws_lambda_function.dev-maintenance.function_name
}

and finally I am containerizing everything so that docker will build the zip file.
Dockerfile:
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /dir
COPY . /dir

# Install TypeScript globally
RUN npm install -g typescript

WORKDIR /dir/lambdas/notifications
RUN npm ci && npm run all

WORKDIR /dir/lambdas/maintenance
RUN npm ci && npm run all

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

My npm run all basically does npm run build && del -f lambda_batch.zip && npm run zip for both lambda functions (just different names for the zip file). Everything seems to be succeeding in the pipeline but my lambda function isn't updating.. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

What does the terraform plan output look like from that run? Please include that in your question.

After a bunch of trial and error, I finally managed to figure it out by using artifacts in gitlab. Basically I had to add artifacts to the docker stage by doing:
build-dev-docker:
  extends: .kaniko-package
  stage: package
  variables:
    KANIKO_BUILD_ARGS: "--build-arg ENVIRONMENT=development --single-snapshot"
    EXTRA_DOCKER_TAG: "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG:$CI_PIPELINE_IID"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - lambdas/batched_notifications/lambda_batch.zip
      - lambdas/maintenance/lambda_maintenance.zip
  only:
    refs:
      - develop
  environment:
    name: dev
  tags:
    - $CDP_K8S_LARGE

The important piece is to add the path to the zip file in the artifacts section and ALSO you have to copy the zip files in your Dockerfile. If you don't do this, it'll still grab the old zip files and not the zip files that are generated in the docker container. So also remember to do this in the dockerfile:
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /dir
COPY . /dir

# Install TypeScript globally
RUN npm install -g typescript

WORKDIR /dir/lambdas/notifications
RUN npm ci && npm run all
RUN cp lambda_batch.zip /builds/dir/lambdas/notifications

WORKDIR /dir/lambdas/maintenance
RUN npm ci && npm run all
RUN cp lambda_maintenance.zip /builds/dir/lambdas/maintenance

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

Another alternative that does work is doing npm run all in the script, so like this:
install_dependencies:
  image: node:18.19.0
  stage: package
  script:
    - cd lambdas/notifications
    - npm ci --cache --prefer-offline
    - npm run all
    - cd ../maintenance
    - npm ci --cache --prefer-offline
    - npm run all
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
      - lambdas/notifications/node_modules/
      - lambdas/maintenance/node_modules/
  tags:
    - $CDP_K8S_LARGE

I also want to address that using terraform via archive_file does work but I ran into the issue where the lambda function code on AWS Lambdas would be uploaded in typescript rather than javascript (since my lambda functions are in typescript and the npm run all converts the zip file into javascript), so that's why I ended up going the docker route!

If the file is not in the current working directory you'll need to use path.module instead of var.PROJECT_DIR like this
resource "aws_lambda_function" "dev-maintenance" {
    function_name = "dev-maintenance"
    role = var.iam_role_arn
    handler = "index.handler"
    runtime = "nodejs20.x"

    filename = "${path.module}/lambdas/maintenance/lambda_maintenance.zip"
    source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("${path.module}/lambdas/maintenance/lambda_maintenance.zip")

    tags = {
        Application = "dev"
        Ou = "dev"
    }
}

Also, I'm not sure why are you zipping the file via npm config. However, you can do it via terraform using archive_file data source,
data "archive_file" "lambda_archive" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/lambdas/maintenance/lambda_maintenance.js" 
  output_path = "${path.module}/lambdas/maintenance/lambda_maintenance.zip"
}


That does work but now I'm running into the issue where the code in the lambda function breaks the lambda since it's in typescript instead of javascript. previously zipping through npm would do cd dist && bestzip ../lambda_test.zip * ../node_modules but now it's zipping the typescript files and uploading that to the lambda function...
